# Consolibyte Quickbooks Integration with Yii

Tags: php, yii, yii2, quickbooks-online

I have been using https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php with Yii2 framework. I have created a model wherein I am using functions and classes provided by consolibyte/quickbooks-php like - `QuickBooks_Utilities`

But this gives an error everytime `app\models\QuickBooks_Utilities`

Ideally this should load the `QuickBooks_Utilities` located in `Utilities.php` vendor/package file.

My code is integrating `Quickbooks.php` using composer autoload and this this further calls a function `QuickBooks_Loader::load('/QuickBooks/Utilities.php');` but still, `QuickBooks_Utilities` does not work.

**Composer.json**

composer require consolibyte/quickbooks

**Code:**
- `QuickbooksController`

```
public function actionIndex(){

        $token = '625595b2b8a42b4b96bb0fab2d224bdadf47';
        $oauth_consumer_key = 'qyprd7MSH5ZXww7eoEFBD7aTNusgiP';
        $oauth_consumer_secret = 'EpvOWiOiwCyXNbSGeh16zDc7jp3wj1oyCgXjWV4I';
        $sandbox = true;

        $quickbooks_oauth_url = 'https://quickbooks.yiishoot-xyrin.c9users.io/oauth.php';
        $quickbooks_success_url = 'https://quickbooks.yiishoot-xyrin.c9users.io/success.php';
        $quickbooks_menu_url = 'https://quickbooks.yiishoot-xyrin.c9users.io/menu.php';
        $dsn = 'mysqli://xyrin:@localhost/quickbooks';
        $encryption_key = 'bcde1234';
        $the_username = 'DO_NOT_CHANGE_ME';
        $the_tenant = 12345;

        if (!QuickBooks_Utilities::initialized($dsn)){
            // Initialize creates the neccessary database schema for queueing up requests and logging
            QuickBooks_Utilities::initialize($dsn);
        }

        $IntuitAnywhere = new QuickBooks_IPP_IntuitAnywhere($dsn, $encryption_key, $oauth_consumer_key, $oauth_consumer_secret, $quickbooks_oauth_url, $quickbooks_success_url);

        if ($IntuitAnywhere->check($the_username, $the_tenant) and $IntuitAnywhere->test($the_username, $the_tenant)){
            $quickbooks_is_connected = true;
            $IPP = new QuickBooks_IPP($dsn);
            $creds = $IntuitAnywhere->load($the_username, $the_tenant);
            $IPP->authMode(
                QuickBooks_IPP::AUTHMODE_OAUTH, 
                $the_username, 
                $creds);

            if ($sandbox){
                $IPP->sandbox(true);
            }

            $realm = $creds['qb_realm'];
            $Context = $IPP->context();
            $CompanyInfoService = new QuickBooks_IPP_Service_CompanyInfo();
            $quickbooks_CompanyInfo = $CompanyInfoService->get($Context, $realm);
        }else{
            $quickbooks_is_connected = false;
        }

}
```

**Error**

> [10.240.1.14][-][-][error][yii\base\ErrorException:1] exception
>   'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class
>   'app\models\QuickBooks_Utilities' not found' in
>   /home/ubuntu/workspace/basic/controllers/QuickbooksController.php

Comment: You'll need to include the actual error so that we have something to work with here.

Comment: Firstly check if main file QuickBooks.php is included by composer autoloader. Try to debug it by eg. `var_dump(QUICKBOOKS_TIMESTAMP);`

Comment: Yes, I have checked this out and I see the file is included.
Getting this - /vendor/consolibyte/quickbooks/QuickBooks.php:3:string 'QUICKBOOKS_TIMESTAMP' (length=20)

Comment: This is the actual error - 2017-03-21 11:38:09 [10.240.1.30][-][-][error][yii\base\ErrorException:1] exception 'yii\base\ErrorException' with message 'Class 'app\models\QuickBooks_Utilities' not found'

Comment: Edit your question and post your code and the actual error. Until you do that, we can't help.

Comment: I have edited the code, please suggest if there is anything I can help you with you to understand.